# How to use 'icc' if i only installed the latest Intel HPC toolkit?

Tags: intel, icc, intelhpc

I want to use 'icc' not 'icx', but it seems that 'icc' has been fully replaced by 'icx' in the Intel HPC toolkit.

I found a method but i can't use it:
wget apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/…
apt-key add GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB
echo "deb apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-oneapi.list
apt-get update
apt-get install intel-oneapi-compiler-dpcpp-cpp-and-cpp-classic

However, when i went 'apt-get update',it told me 'E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-oneapi.list (URI parse) E: The list of sources could not be read.' .
Then i have no idea what to do.

Can someone tell me how to get 'icc'?

Answer (score 0):

Intel® C++ Compiler Classic (icc) is removed in the oneAPI 2024.0 release. Intel recommends that customers transition to using the LLVM-based Intel® oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler (icx) for continued Windows* and Linux* support, new language support, new language features, and optimizations.

For more information on icx, see the [Intel® oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler Developer Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2024-0/invoke-the-compiler.html) and Reference and the [Porting Guide for ICC Users to DPCPP or ICX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/porting-guide-for-icc-users-to-dpcpp-or-icx.html).

Intel® C++ Compiler Classic (icc) will still be available in older versions of Intel oneAPI toolkits. If you wish to download these older versions, kindly post your query on [oneAPI Registration, Download, Licensing, and Installation forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/bd-p/registration-download-licensing-instal).